# VB.net Open new IE window

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, url, button

another one I cannot seem to find. But in vb.net, how do I force a new instance of IE or Chrome when clicking a button?

I may have already existing windows open, but I want to make it where when I click my button, it opens either Chrome, IE, etc. open new instance.

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: `Dim IE2 As Object = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")`

Comment: That fails with my code:

CODE:
Dim IE2 As Object = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
GOOGLEString = TextBox1.Text
                    Dim GOOGLEUri As New Uri(IE2, "http://google.com/search?hl=en&q=" & GOOGLEString)
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(GOOGLEUri.AbsoluteUri)

Comment: Please edit your question to show code. Anyway the code I wrote uses `.Navigate` to open a page: is exacly a browser

Answer (score 1):

The exe's should be in path so you can just run them like this

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--new-window http://www.bing.com")
Process.Start("iexplore.exe", "http://www.bing.com")
```

If they aren't in path, you'll need to provide the full path to the exe, like `c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe`

By default on my system chrome opens up a new tab if you run chrome.exe without the `--new-window` parameter. When I run iexplore.exe, it always opens up a new window by default.

Comment: The iexplore part works but the chrome does not with passing textbox text to it.

Comment: What doesn't work specifically, and what error do you get? Did you try using the full path to Chrome? `c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\chrome\Application\chrome.exe`

Comment: I try this:
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe" "--new-window", SLBUri.AbsoluteUri)`
And that just opens chrome with no URL

Comment: Your arguments for the process should be a single string, not another parameter. `"--new-window " + SLBUri.AbsoluteUri`